# Image is not showing on website fully and it crash a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have an issue with upload images on server and then show it on site. Backend is running in sailsjs + angular.js but templete where I show image is predefined and there is only js/html.

There are two case :
1 – all working as it should
2 – it not working as should

1)  I upload image that size is to 107kb, it upload to server fully, application is not shutdown, image is showed in website

2)  I upload image that size are more then 107kb, it upload to server full, application is restart with backend, one half of image are shown in the website  (app is crashing).

Firstly I think that problem is with size, but I upload image without showing it on website and everything is working good. So the problem is with showing it. 
This is from logs of this error.

```
Error: write after end
at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:627:15)
at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:622:10)
at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:651:20)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:180:13)
at ReadStream.emit (domain.js:422:20)
at ReadStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:487:10)
at flow (_stream_readable.js:858:34)
at ServerResponse.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:719:7)
at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:180:13)
at ServerResponse.emit (domain.js:422:20)
at Socket.ondrain (internal/http.js:20:44)
at Socket.emit (events.js:185:15)
at Socket.emit (domain.js:422:20)
at onwriteDrain (_stream_writable.js:487:12)
at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:475:5)
at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:468:7)
```

This code is for upload :
[here](https://privatebin.net/?b3440e895873cd96#H5edeVrVMFxfLnmTYdzqWKb2xAi1aR3K7wBBkMpUmzJL)

And this code show image on website :

```
previewIframe.$('.js-asset img').attr('src', uploadedPath); // tmp path
```

Comment: please clarify the architecture on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code to handle images (and all non-video), you have the

```
fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
```

It's fine to pipe your file to response, but you need to first write your HTTP header, then stream in your data:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
```

or, using a more explicit vocabulary:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
const stream = fs.createReadStream(path);
stream.on('data', stuff => {
    res.write(stuff);
});
stream.on('end',() => {
    // explicitly close the response
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Hey,

It help me to upload files to max 2mb, but still at 2.24MB is the same error.
Do you have any idea what could help me more?

Comment: Sure. I think you may be prematurely hitting the `res.end()` part of your code, before your image is finished streaming. My advice it to remove `res.end()` from the bottom of your code. Remember that `fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)` is not a synchronous operation

Answer (score 1):

It may happen that the "templete" part takes the uploaded image before it is completely uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code is asyncronous, so when you are uploading a file, the response is sent before the file is actually written. Try making your code synchronous with async/await.

PS: The link you shared doesnot have any code in it.

Comment: Link is expired:
Here is a new one.
https://privatebin.net/?b3440e895873cd96#H5edeVrVMFxfLnmTYdzqWKb2xAi1aR3K7wBBkMpUmzJL

About this async : in this are all working good. File is starting to upload, is saved fully, then it is copied to proper folder, and there is genereted link to it, the link is going there to img src. Everyting is going step by step. I think problem is with config of node/sails. Becouse even a mp4 that are loaded using chunks is loading really slow :/ But i tried a lot of config any there is no help. Also i cant get you access to service (its beyond VPN of my company)

Answer (score 1):

Having only parts of a uploaded file strongly sounds like you need to *flush* the stream to disk before doing anything else. Also maybe you didn't close the stream first.